# Getting Users and groups from Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I have a web application secured by Keycloak. Now I want to read all the security groups and users from keycloak in my application. Is it possible?

Comment: How do you want to read the information? Through shell or some other way?

Comment: I want too get this information in my bean class after the user is logged in through Kecloak. I need the user list  to pass it to the services.

Comment: From my knowledge, there are "admin client" libraries out there that can make this easy for you, e.g. for Java: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-admin-client

Answer (score 1):

Keycloak has a very good documentation around the APIs.
I believe you are looking to get all the groups and users from the Keycloak. It could be as straightforward as calling any REST APIs.

You can follow this [link](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_groups_resource) to get all the groups from the Keycloak.
And this [link](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource) to get the users based on the given search criteria.

But I would be wary of the performance implication it might have calling these APIs. Make sure to use pagination and appropriate filters for getting users.

Also, if you want, you can write a custom extension in Keycloak to serve your purpose. You can follow this [link](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_extensions_rest) for it.

Comment: Some URLs are dead. https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/16.1/rest-api/index.html#_groups_resource and https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/16.1/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource seem to be replacements

Answer (score -1):

I could get the access token using the client secret key using the curl command from command line.

```
$curl  -X POST -d "client_id=my_client"   -d "username=username"   -d "client_secret=c957b0ba-c421-4021-8433-764aa2fwes72"   -d "grant_type=client_credentials"   HOST/auth/realms/my_realm/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

I could also get the list of users after getting the access token

```
$curl -X GET HOST/auth/admin/realms/my_realm/users -H "Authorization: Bearer access-token" -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

Now, I'm thinking how can I do this from my web application.